# as.Date returns NA date format

Tags: r, na, as.date

My date format is "Sat 12 Sep" as character.
I want to transform it into Date format in a new column called DATE.

```
mutate(DATE = (as.Date(FECHA, "%a %d %b")))
```

but it returns NA

```
 X      FECHA        LOCAL       RESULT   VISITANTE       DATE      
 <int>  <chr>        <fct>       <fct>    <fct>           <date>    
 1      3 **Sat 12 Sep** Eibar   0 - 0    Celta Vigo      NA        
 2      4 Sat 12 Sep Granada     2 - 0    Athletic Bilbao NA
```

Thanks

Comment: what is "FECHA"

Comment: FECHA is the column  where is  "Sat 12 Sep"

Comment: Please post a reproducible example of your data using ``dput()`` rather than an image and read [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example). Thank you.

Comment: Run `Sys.setlocale("LC_TIME", "English")` before your code,

Comment: It works Roland

Comment: Thank you Roland  it was the solution

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would recommend looking at the lubridate package. It will add 2020 as the year automatically (be careful if that is not what you want).

See if this works for you:

```
library(lubridate)

x <- "Sat 12 Sep"

parse_date_time(x, "%a %d %b", locale = "UK")
[1] "2020-09-12 UTC"
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is a solution using `base` with `data.frame` for your sample data and `as.Date` to convert from the `FECHA` variable from `character` to `date`.

**Code:**

```r
Sys.setlocale("LC_TIME", "English")

df <- data.frame(X = as.integer(c(3, 4)),
                 FECHA = as.character(c("Sat 12 Sep", "Sat 12 Sep")),
                 LOCAL = as.factor(c("Eibar", "Granada")),
                 RESULT = as.factor(c("0 - 0", "2 - 0")),
                 VISITANTE = as.factor(c("Celta Vido", "Athletic Bilbao")),
                 DATE = as.Date(c(NA, NA)))

df$DATE <- as.Date(df$FECHA, format = "%a %d %B")
```

**Output:**

```
#>   X      FECHA   LOCAL RESULT       VISITANTE       DATE
#> 1 3 Sat 12 Sep   Eibar  0 - 0      Celta Vido 2020-09-12
#> 2 4 Sat 12 Sep Granada  2 - 0 Athletic Bilbao 2020-09-12
```

<sup>Created on 2020-10-19 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.3.0)</sup>

**Original Output:**

```r
#>   X      FECHA   LOCAL RESULT       VISITANTE DATE
#> 1 3 Sat 12 Sep   Eibar  0 - 0      Celta Vido <NA>
#> 2 4 Sat 12 Sep Granada  2 - 0 Athletic Bilbao <NA>
```

<sup>Created on 2020-10-19 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.3.0)</sup>

Comment: This won't work in OP's locale. The issue is that an English locale is needed to parse "Sat"  and "Sep". The character method of `as.Date` doesn't have a `tz` parameter (which only affects the time zone anyway, not the locale).

Comment: @Roland - Do you mind if I borrow from your comment and add it to my solution? `Sys.setlocale("LC_TIME", "English")` before the code for a locale-specific version of the date.